# How to add smtp in normal php mailer

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer

Our email client use smtp, I like to add smtp details in following emailer I tried but its not working, there is any other way to fix this code?

```
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Host = "smtp.example.com";
$mail->Port = 26;
$mail->Username = "#@#@#@#@-####-@@@@-#####-@#@#@#@#@#@#";
$mail->Password = "#@#@#@#@-####-@@@@-#####-@#@#@#@#@#@#";

$mailto = "info@example.com";
$subject = "Test mail";  

// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

// Create email headers
$headers = 'From: support@exmaple.com'. "\r\n". 
'Reply-To: '.$email."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();   

$email_message .= "First Name: $fname \r\n";
$email_message .= "Last Name: $lname \r\n";
$email_message .= "Designation: $designation \r\n";
$email_message .= "Email: $email \r\n";
$email_message .= "Phone Number: $phonenumber \r\n";

@mail($mail, $mailto, $subject, $email_message, $headers);
```

Comment: This is a mess. Either use PHPMailer, or use mail() - you have a weird mixture that will not work in either. Base your code on [the gmail example provided with PHMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail.phps).

Answer (score 0):

Please add SMTP Secure and try this again,

```
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; 
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Mailer = "smtp";
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->Username = "YOU@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = "YOUR_GMAIL_password";
```

Comment: This is wrong: `tls` mode (SMTP+STARTTLS) won't work on port 465. Either change `SMTPSecure` to `ssl` or change `Port` to `587`.

Comment: How do you know that the OP's SMTP server supports encryption in the first place? And why do yo assume that the OP is sending through Gmail? Regardless, the OP can set what ever they want in PHPMailer. It won't do any difference since the OP is actually sending the mail through PHP's `mail()`, which is _not_ interchangeable with PHPMailer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a working example of phpmailer

```
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail->isSMTP();

$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;

$mail->Host = $host;
$mail->Port = $port;

$mail->SMTPAuth = true;

if($authtype){
 $mail->SMTPSecure = ($authtype > 1 ? 'tls' : 'ssl');
}

$mail->Username = $user;
$mail->Password = $pass;

$mail->setFrom($sender, $name);
$mail->addReplyTo($sender, $name);
$mail->addAddress($recipient, $recipient);

$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->msgHTML($message);

$message = preg_split('/<br(\s*\/\s*)?>/i', $message);
$message = array_map('trim', $message);
$message = implode("\n", $message);

$mail->AltBody = $message;

$mail->send();
```

Comment: Where an how is `$authtype` set? Magic numbers?

Comment: As you can see, all variables ($host, $port, $authtype, $user, $pass, $sender, $name, $recipient, $subject, $message) have to be set before calling the script. I thought this would be clear for everyone. But I was wrong. Sorry. And I hope it is clear for you now.

Comment: I did get that, but when you post a "working example", it should contain the full script (including the variable definitions). Also, my point was that you clearly set `$authtype` as an integer without explaining in your answer what number means what. Sure, we can read the code and see what's what, but a good answer doesn't require the users to reverse engineer things. You might also want to mention that your regex-code converts HTML line breaks to normal line breaks, which doesn't seem to be necessary in the OP's question.